# How to avoid PreferenceScreen in FragmentPreference creating an activity?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to create a setting UI based on drawer. I have added `PreferenceFragment` to a fragment of drawer, hare is my code:

PrefFragment.java

```
public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_frag);
    }
}
```

DrawerActivity:

```
//start to add a prefFragment
PreferenceFragment prefFrag = new PrefFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_container, prefFrag).commit();
```

pref_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="pref fragment"/>

    <EditTextPreference
            android:title="edit"/>

    <PreferenceScreen> <!--daunt-->
        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:title="inner pref screen"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

But this causes a problem, I open the inner `PreferencesScreen` , it open an activity and no drawer can be slided out, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Fragments can't live without an activity.

Comment: This is how the preference function works -- the subscreen is another activity.  To do what you want to do, you need to code your own fragments for setting preferences and not use PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @krislarson I got your idea, I can replace current fragment with another fragment, but I think this is not the best practice, or what I want to do is not recommanded by Android